# House loses value each year. How long will it take for the house to be worth $150000

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

A house purchased for $\$226000$ loses $4\%$ of its value each year. How long will it take for the house to be worth $\$150000$?

The way I set up the equation was $150000=(226000)(.96)^x$.  I just wasn't sure that was right.

Comment: Have you tried setting up an equation to solve? Do you know about logarithms?

Comment: Yes the way I set the equation was 150000=(226000)(.96)^(x)

Comment: that looks right to me... can you solve it from there?

Comment: Yea,thanks I just wasn't too sure if I was setting the equation right.

Answer (score 2):

$150000=226000(0.96)^t$

Now divide both sides by $226000$.

$0.6673=(0.96)^t$

The next step is this:

$t = \dfrac{\log 0.6673}{\log 0.96} \approx 10$ years

I hope this helps! Just remember that if $a=b^x$ then $x= \dfrac{\log a}{\log b}$.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on formatting mathematics on this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes, that could be helpful :) I'm new here on stackexchange. Thanks!